# c# Multi Threading only using 25% of CPU

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I have a process for a sort of genetic nesting algorithm that I am trying to multi-thread. The process looks something like the following.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      CurrentNest = new CuttingRun();
      for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++)
      {
        double w = GetRandomNumber(24, 50);
        double h = GetRandomNumber(10, 15);
        CurrentNest.PartList.Add(new LwCube { Width = w, Height = h, PartID = i });
      }
      //Task.Run(() =>
      //{
      //  Parallel.For(0, 64, (i) => Parallel_Nest());
      //});
      while (true)
      {
        Parallel_Nest();
      }
      //Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static double GetRandomNumber(double minimum, double maximum)
    {
      Random random = new Random();
      return random.NextDouble() * (maximum - minimum) + minimum;
    }

    public static CuttingRun CurrentNest { get; set; }
    public static void Parallel_Nest()
    {
      Random random = new Random();
      int randomNumber = random.Next(2000, 10000);     
      var retVal = Nester.Nest_Parts(CurrentNest, randomNumber);
      CurrentNest.Iterations++;
      if (CurrentNest.SavedList.Count > 0)
      {
        if (retVal.Count < CurrentNest.SavedList.Count)
        {
          CurrentNest.SavedList = retVal;          
        }
      }
      else
      {
        CurrentNest.SavedList = retVal;
      }
      Console.WriteLine(CurrentNest.Iterations.ToString() + " " + CurrentNest.SavedList.Count.ToString());
      if (CurrentNest.SavedList != retVal)
      {
        retVal.Clear();
      }
    }    
  }


//Models
public class LwSheet
  {
    public LwSheet(double width, double height)
    {
      SheetWidth = width;
      SheetHeight = height;
      FreeRectangles.Add(new LwCube { Width = width, Height = height, X = 0, Y = 0 });
    }
    public List<LwCube> UsedRectangles = new List<LwCube>();
    public List<LwCube> FreeRectangles = new List<LwCube>();
    public double SheetWidth { get; set; }
    public double SheetHeight { get; set; }
    public double TotalUsed { get; set; }
    public bool Place_Part(LwCube prt)
    {
      bool retVal = false;
      LwCube bestNode = FindPositionForBestAreaFit(prt);
      //if the bestNode has a height then add our parts to the list
      if (bestNode.Height > 0)
      {
        bestNode.PartID = prt.PartID;
        int numRectanglesToProcess = FreeRectangles.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < numRectanglesToProcess; ++i)
        {
          if (SplitFreeNode(FreeRectangles[i], ref bestNode))
          {
            FreeRectangles.RemoveAt(i);
            --i;
            --numRectanglesToProcess;
          }
        }

        PruneFreeList();
        UsedRectangles.Add(bestNode);
        retVal = true;
      }
      return retVal;
    }
    bool SplitFreeNode(LwCube freeNode, ref LwCube usedNode)
    {
      // Test with SAT if the rectangles even intersect.
      if (usedNode.X >= freeNode.X + freeNode.Width || usedNode.X + usedNode.Width <= freeNode.X ||
        usedNode.Y >= freeNode.Y + freeNode.Height || usedNode.Y + usedNode.Height <= freeNode.Y)
        return false;

      if (usedNode.X < freeNode.X + freeNode.Width && usedNode.X + usedNode.Width > freeNode.X)
      {
        // New node at the top side of the used node.
        if (usedNode.Y > freeNode.Y && usedNode.Y < freeNode.Y + freeNode.Height)
        {
          LwCube newNode = new LwCube { Width = freeNode.Width, X = freeNode.X, Y = freeNode.Y };
          newNode.Height = usedNode.Y - newNode.Y;
          FreeRectangles.Add(newNode);
        }

        // New node at the bottom side of the used node.
        if (usedNode.Y + usedNode.Height < freeNode.Y + freeNode.Height)
        {
          LwCube newNode = new LwCube { Width = freeNode.Width, X = freeNode.X };
          newNode.Y = usedNode.Y + usedNode.Height;
          newNode.Height = freeNode.Y + freeNode.Height - (usedNode.Y + usedNode.Height);
          FreeRectangles.Add(newNode);
        }
      }

      if (usedNode.Y < freeNode.Y + freeNode.Height && usedNode.Y + usedNode.Height > freeNode.Y)
      {
        // New node at the left side of the used node.
        if (usedNode.X > freeNode.X && usedNode.X < freeNode.X + freeNode.Width)
        {
          LwCube newNode = new LwCube { Height = freeNode.Height, X = freeNode.X, Y = freeNode.Y };
          newNode.Width = usedNode.X - newNode.X;
          FreeRectangles.Add(newNode);
        }

        // New node at the right side of the used node.
        if (usedNode.X + usedNode.Width < freeNode.X + freeNode.Width)
        {
          LwCube newNode = new LwCube { Height = freeNode.Height, Y = freeNode.Y };
          newNode.X = usedNode.X + usedNode.Width;
          newNode.Width = freeNode.X + freeNode.Width - (usedNode.X + usedNode.Width);
          FreeRectangles.Add(newNode);
        }
      }

      return true;
    }    
    void PruneFreeList()
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < FreeRectangles.Count; ++i)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < FreeRectangles.Count; ++j)
        {
          if (IsContainedIn(FreeRectangles[i], FreeRectangles[j]))
          {
            FreeRectangles.RemoveAt(i);
            --i;
            break;
          }
          if (IsContainedIn(FreeRectangles[j], FreeRectangles[i]))
          {
            FreeRectangles.RemoveAt(j);
            --j;
          }
        }
    }
    bool IsContainedIn(LwCube a, LwCube b)
    {
      return a.X >= b.X && a.Y >= b.Y
        && a.X + a.Width <= b.X + b.Width
        && a.Y + a.Height <= b.Y + b.Height;
    }
    LwCube FindPositionForBestAreaFit(LwCube prt)
    {
      LwCube bestNode = new LwCube();
      var bestAreaFit = SheetWidth * SheetHeight;
      for (int i = 0; i < FreeRectangles.Count; ++i)
      {
        double areaFit = FreeRectangles[i].Width * FreeRectangles[i].Height - prt.Width * prt.Height;

        // Try to place the rectangle in upright (non-flipped) orientation.
        if (FreeRectangles[i].Width >= prt.Width && FreeRectangles[i].Height >= prt.Height)
        {
          if (areaFit < bestAreaFit)
          {
            bestNode.X = FreeRectangles[i].X;
            bestNode.Y = FreeRectangles[i].Y;
            bestNode.Height = prt.Height;
            bestNode.Width = prt.Width;
            bestAreaFit = areaFit;
          }
        }
      }
      return bestNode;
    }   
  }

  public class LwCube
  {
    public int PartID { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
  }

  public class CuttingRun
  {    
    public List<LwCube> PartList = new List<LwCube>();
    public List<LwSheet> SavedList = new List<LwSheet>();
    public List<LwSheet> Sheets = new List<LwSheet>();
    public int Iterations { get; set; }
  }


//Actions
public static class Nester
  {
    public static List<LwSheet> Nest_Parts(CuttingRun cuttingRun, int loopCount)
    {
      var SheetList = new List<LwSheet>();
      List<LwCube> partList = new List<LwCube>();
      partList.AddRange(cuttingRun.PartList);
      while (partList.Count > 0)
      {
        LwSheet newScore = new LwSheet(97, 49);
        List<LwCube> addingParts = new List<LwCube>();
        foreach (var prt in partList)
        {
          addingParts.Add(new LwCube { Width = prt.Width, Height = prt.Height, PartID = prt.PartID });
        }
        if (addingParts.Count > 0)
        {
          var sheets = new ConcurrentBag<LwSheet>();
          Parallel.For(0, loopCount, (i) =>
          {
            var hmr = new LwSheet(97, 49);
            Add_Parts_To_Sheet(hmr, addingParts);
            sheets.Add(hmr);
          });
          //for (int i = 0; i < loopCount; i++)
          //{
          //  var hmr = new LwSheet(97, 49);

          //  Add_Parts_To_Sheet(hmr, addingParts, addToLarge, addToMedium);
          //  sheets.Add(hmr);
          //}
          addingParts.Clear();
          var bestSheet = sheets.Where(p => p != null).OrderByDescending(p => p.TotalUsed).First();
          sheets = null;
          newScore = bestSheet;
          foreach (var ur in newScore.UsedRectangles)
          {
            partList.Remove(partList.Single(p => p.PartID == ur.PartID));
          }
          SheetList.Add(newScore);
        }
      }
      return SheetList;
    }       
    public static void Add_Parts_To_Sheet(LwSheet sh, List<LwCube> parts)
    {
      var myList = new List<LwCube>();
      myList.AddRange(parts);
      myList.Shuffle();
      foreach (var prt in myList)
      {
        sh.Place_Part(prt);
      }
      myList.Clear();
      foreach (var ur in sh.UsedRectangles)
      {
        sh.TotalUsed += ur.Width * ur.Height;
      }
    }

    [ThreadStatic] private static Random Local;
    public static Random ThisThreadsRandom
    {
      get { return Local ?? (Local = new Random(unchecked(Environment.TickCount * 31 + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId))); }
    }

    public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)
    {
      int n = list.Count;
      while (n > 1)
      {
        n--;
        int k = ThisThreadsRandom.Next(n + 1);
        T value = list[k];
        list[k] = list[n];
        list[n] = value;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried using parallel for loops on each of the loops to try and speed up the process. I have also tried changing them to tasks and used task.WhenAll. However I am only able to use around 25% of my CPU. If I start the program 4 different times, I can use 100%.
I am wondering if anyone has any ideas on how I could use 100% of my CPU without starting the program more than once?
EDIT: After adding a scaled down working version I also commented out one of the parallel loops and one of the normal loops to show where I put them in the code.

Comment: Can you show the parallel loop you are calling this in?

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? Parallelism doesn't mean loops. If you want that method to consume parts, it's better to use a queue for them and pop them as needed instead of removing stuff

Comment: There's some really weird code in here. Two nested `for` loops which do nothing; a `for` loop using a combination of `I` and `i `(neither of which are declared)

Comment: How many cores does your CPU have? Are you only starting 2 threads? The short answer is probably going to be "Start more threads", but there isnt enough code here to give you a definitive answer. If theres some kind of network connection or heavy drive activity going on, you might not be able to get to 100% CPU because thats not the bottleneck. Also why would you want to use 100% of the CPU? Just to see if you can?

Comment: Please post code that compiles at least. Then show what you did to spread it over multiple processors.

Comment: There's no `ParallelForEachAsync` method, `await Nest_Parts` won't even compile because `Nest_Parts` doesn't return Task and even if it did, it doesn't do anything asynchronously. This won't even compile

Comment: Be aware that List<T> is *not* thread-safe. Consider using one of the [thread-safe collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/).

Comment: this is not thread safe either... so mixing to many things at once.@yawnston you just beat me

Comment: OP said process looks something like the following, indicating this is psuedo code.

Comment: That is the case. In order to put all of the code in here I would have 20 pages of code. I was trying to give a general idea of what my code does to see if anyone else had run into something similar. I am using a Ryzan ThreadRipper with 32 Cores and 64 Threads.

Comment: add code for Add_Parts_To_Sheet

Comment: added the method, still just a generalisation but should give the idea hopefully.

Comment: _"In order to put all of the code in here I would have 20 pages of code"_ -- nobody is asking for **all** of the code. Your responsibility as the person asking the question is to construct a [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. That means you need to put some effort in, and distill the _essence_ of your problem into a code example that is _not_ _"20 pages of code"_. Please also read [ask] where you can find additional advice about how to present your question in a clerar, answerable way. Pay particular note to the web articles linked at the bottom of that page.

Answer (score 2):

> However I am only able to use around 25% of my CPU. If I start the program 4 different times, I can use 100%. I am wondering if anyone has any ideas on how I could use 100% of my CPU without starting the program more than once?

Your code appears to be a mixture of asynchronous (presumably I/O-bound) and parallel (presumably CPU-bound) portions. I say "appears to be" because we can't say for sure where the problem is since this is not a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

But, if that assumption is correct, then the reason your CPU is underutilized is simple: the parallel CPU-bound portions are waiting for their input data from the asynchronous I/O-bound portions. The only way to fix that is to run the I/O-bound portions concurrently. Move your I/O-bound code as early in the pipeline as possible, and then be sure to run the I/O-bound portions as concurrently as possible. E.g., if you have to call a WebApi for each item, call it as soon as you have the item; or if you're reading items from a database, try to read as many in a batch as possible. This is to minimize the amount of time that the CPU-bound portions have to wait for their data.

"Asynchronous Parallel ForEach" is rarely a good tool for this kind of problem. I would either look into TPL Dataflow or build your own pipeline using Channels.

At the end of the day, it is possible that the algorithm as a whole is I/O-bound. In that case, there isn't a whole lot you can do: only one CPU would be used because the I/O couldn't even keep up with that single CPU, and in that case using more CPUs wouldn't provide any benefit.

Comment: Stephen, thank you for the post. All of the I/O -bound things are done prior to these 2 loops. The Add_Parts_To_Sheet method is a fair bit more complicated to decide how and where to place a part, however the most cpu intense item in there is a Random. I will look into the TPL dataflow and see if that works.

Comment: If all the I/O is already done, then what are you using `await` for?

Comment: That was just one of the ways I was trying to multi-thread. I also tried a typical parallel for as well as background workers as not to lock the UI

Comment: @JonahKunz: You should use a regular `Parallel` call. If you need to unblock the UI, wrap it in `await Task.Run`.

Comment: Sorry first commend didn't work, I added a working version. Would you mind taking a look?

Comment: @JonahKunz: That's still a *lot* of code to go through. I recommend reducing it further. Replace actual logic with busy-loops as much as possible, and simplify it until it literally cannot be simplified any more. (Side note: what *usually* happens during this process is that the asker finds the problem themselves during the simplification exercise).